# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array PHP

Tags: php, html

I created this peace of PHP code to connect to googlew sheet and fill html file on my server:

```
 <?php

// Vaš Google Sheets API ključ
$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// URL vašeg Google Sheet-a
$sheet_url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Kreiranje URL-a za zahtev
$request_url = $sheet_url . '?key=' . $api_key;

// Povezivanje sa Google Sheets API-jem pomoću cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Parsiranje JSON odgovora
$data = json_decode($response);

// Popunjavanje podataka u HTML dokument
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');
foreach ($data as $datapoint) {
    // Provjera da li se datum u koloni podudara sa trenutnim datumom
    if ($datapoint['datum'] == date('d.m')) {
        $html = str_replace('{{IME}}', $datapoint['Ime'], $html);
        $html = str_replace('{{PREZIME}}', $datapoint['Prezime'], $html);
        $html = str_replace('{{ULICA}}', $datapoint['Ulica'], $html);
        $html = str_replace('{{BROJ}}', $datapoint['E-mail'], $html);
    }
}

// Postavljanje HTTP zaglavlja za datoteku
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="popunjeno.html"');

// Prikazivanje HTML dokumenta sa popunjenim podacima
echo $html;

?>
```

But I got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/sheet2html.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/sheet2html.php on line 26

This script should populate HTML file from google sheet on with data from today only.

Maybe because it is late, maybe my knowledge is limited, I googled couple og hours, but mainly found this errors in JSON calls for example. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's in the google JSON response, but chances are it's being decoded into an instance of [stdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stdclass.php) by this line:

```php
$data = json_decode($response);
```

if `$data` is an instance of stdClass, you can' use foreach on it unless you cast it as an array. Fortunately, [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) allows you to provide an additional second parameter, `$associative` to force it to decode the JSON object as associative arrays (see [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ) instead of stdClass objects. The documentation:

> **associative**
>
> When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; when false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When null, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects depending on whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags.

So you could change your line of code to this:

```php
$data = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

And hopefully that will let you iterate through `$data` using the `foreach` construct.

Comment: Great man, that was that, I really apreciate your help, kudos to you!

Comment: "if $data is an instance of stdClass, you can' use foreach on it"  
Actually, you can. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php
The problem here was not that `$data` was an object but that `$datapoint` was an object.